# Cant add version Qualifier Folder into res/menu in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, version

I have tried right clicking on res and adding new folders and fils with -v11 at the end of the name but I don't see the folder in the res directory when I do this?

I have restared android studio and still don't see them? Or sometimes is says thats an invalid character?

I right click on res and this is what I see then I click new directory.

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The version qualifier starts with a "v". In your instance it would be `menu-v11`. If you don't see it go to Explorer/Finder/whatever and check for the folder presence there.

Also I'm guessing you're trying to provide **different icons for the same menu** for platforms below and above API 11. You do that by providing `drawable-?dpi` and `drawable-?dpi-v11` resources. Then you have a different icon (with same name) for different platforms and only one menu resource which uses the icon.

EDIT: In Android Studio RC 1.0 everytime I create a `layout` resource it puts it in the `/res` folder instead of `/res/layout`. This is a bug and your problem may be related. I would check the parent folder.

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my question not what I was doing